# Ant table column filter with search and select all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to add select all option in ant table column filter. I am able to do this by setting filterMode to true. But in this case searched value shown in bold letters and other options also visible. I want a search option to search matching records and then a select all option to select all sarched items. It should hide other records like it works without filterMode and a select all option. How can we achieve it.